# How to order variables in Maxima?

Tags: maxima

I want to give variables a specific order in an equation in Maxima. This is display purposes only.

For example:

```
(%i1) E=(h*c)/%lambda;
                                c h
(%o1)                     E = -------
                              %lambda
```

I want the `h` and `c` variables to be in that order when displayed. I looked at `ratvars()` and `ordergreat()` but they don't appear to be relevant here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may have found a solution by using the `alias()` function. Unfortunately it's not an available function in my implementation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I also found `declare(<var>, mainvar)` but that's not available either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `declare(<var>, mainvar)` was what I was looking for. When [mainvar attribute](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_6.html#IDX181) is declared for a variable it "[succeeds all other constants and variables](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_11.html#IDX375)".

I was trying this using the STACK plugin for Moodle. I needed to remove the `mainvar` keyword from the forbidden list in the file casstring.class.php.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think ordergreat() is the function you need, maybe you did a sorting before that needed unorder() first ro reset things.
Try

```
unorder()$ ordergreat (h, c)$ E=(h*c)/%lambda;
```

and

```
unorder()$ ordergreat (c, h)$ E=(h*c)/%lambda;
```

Comment: Yes and no. Your solution did work in command line maxima (5.37.2 + CLISP 2.49 + Ubuntu 15.10 and 5.36.0) but not in WXMaxima 16.04. Declare with Mainvar worked in all contexts. I've up-voted your answer because it's still useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate answer: you can also set Maxima (and STACK-Moodle) to display in canonical ordering (rather than its default reverse canonical ordering) by setting powerdisp:true.